# Geb overwrite web driver

Tags: webdriver, htmlunit, geb, htmlunit-driver

I'm running my tests using gradle which is specifying JVM properties in the following manner:

```
-Dgeb.env=dev -Dgeb.driver=org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver
```

This sets driver and configures environment in Geb config script.
I want to enable JavaScript for HtmlUnit after specifying it in environment property. To be more general, I want to overwrite driver in the config script (I'm not interested in setting driver in every test's `setup()` block)

I tried putting the following code snippet in Geb config script:

```
if (System.getProperty("geb.driver")=="org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver") {
    driver = {
        println "Setting JavaScript"
        def driver = new HtmlUnitDriver()
        driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true)
        driver
    }
}
```

This prints out the message but the tests fail due to

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Javascript is not enabled for this HtmlUnitDriver instance
```

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/20095893/2504101

Comment: thanks @olyv but in my case HtmlUnit works fine. I just wanted to set it in the way I do for all drivers like chrome, firefox, ie, phantomjs (by specifying class name in the property). But unfortunately htmlunit doesn't set JavaScript by default during initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised that you're seeing `Setting JavaScript` printed out but what happens is that your driver closure doesn't get called because if you use `geb.driver` system property then Geb creates the driver for you internally based on that. I suggest you either use the env to create the driver in your `GebConfig.groovy` or use a different system property than `geb.driver` to ask for a given driver impl to be used and manage driver creation yourself.

Comment: You're right, I found a place in Geb source code, which is responsible for that: `properties.getProperty("geb.driver") ?: readValue("driver", null)` I decided to workaround this by passing empty `geb.driver` property and setting driver using closure in Geb config script. This allows me to set `geb.driver` for all drivers except of HtmlUnit.